# How do you store 2 hex digits (1 byte) in a single index position of a char array?

Tags: c, serial-port, hex

I am really stumped on the proper way to do this.  I have spent a few days searching, and I can't seem to find a straight answer/explanation on this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: the application this if for, is to send positioning commands to a servo drive.  The format of the char array for serial output is what is required from the servo drive.

So, here is my function:

```
int myFunc(int valOne, int valTwo, int valThree)
{
    char bufferA = 0;
    char bufferB = 0;
    char bufferC = 0;

    sprintf(bufferA, "%02x", valOne);
    sprintf(bufferB, "%02x", valTwo);
    sprintf(bufferC, "%02x", valThree);

    char servoCommand[13] = {0};
    servoCommand[0] = 0x01;
    servoCommand[1] = 0x11;
    servoCommand[2] = 0x09;
    servoCommand[3] = 0x02;
    servoCommand[4] = 0x00;
    servoCommand[5] = 0x02;
    servoCommand[6] = 0x01;
    servoCommand[7] = 0x02;
    servoCommand[8] = bufferA;
    servoCommand[9] = bufferB;
    servoCommand[10] = bufferC;
    servoCommand[11] = 0x00;
    servoCommand[12] = 0x04;

    //.... Code to write to serial port goes down here (this part works fine)

    return 0;
}
```

The output down the COM needs to look something like this:
01 11 09 02 00 02 01 02 40 42 0F 00 04

Each two digit pair is a single byte (where as each digit is technically a nibble?)

The three variables take their input from another function that reads an integer value from a UI slider, or a predefined set of integers from a csv that gets stored in an array.

Bottom line, I need to feed in integers and convert them into hex format, and be able to store 2 hex digits per char array position.  This works fine if you hard code it.  I am having trouble creating a variable that can take the function arguments, and convert it correctly  It wants to occupy more than one position (ie. an array of char[5]).  I think this is because it is trying to convert to ASCII??

Comment: I would add code to assure that each integer parameter is actually in the range 0...15.

Comment: the sprintf() first parameter needs to be the address of the receiving variable.  I.E. sprintf(&bufferA, "%02x", valOne);  however, sprintf will output a trailing null char, so better to use: bufferA = valOne&0xFF;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
servoCommand[8] = valOne;
servoCommand[9] = valTwo;
servoCommand[10] = valThree;
```

You don't need to convert anything. The string `01 11 09 02 00 02 01 02 40 42 0F 00 04` is just a human representation of the actual numeric values sent. Since valOne/Two/Three are already numbers, you can just use them as-is.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks.  For some reason I was very caught up on trying to convert it to hex.  I guess I wasn't really thinking that a number is a number, and it doesn't matter what format it's in.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: isn't it dangerous to have `valOne` as `int`?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely write the code as:

```
servoCommand[8] = (valOne & 0xFF);
servoCommand[9] = (valTwo & 0xFF);
servoCommand[10] = (valThree & 0xFF);
```

This will take up exactly 1 byte (the last byte) from the integer value of 4 bytes.